# User registration and authentication service for iOS app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have completed my iOS app and now want to have user registration and authentication functionality.

When the user opens the app it must ask them to register or login and then when the app closes it logs out.  I want to send their basic details to my server e.g. name, location.

Is this allowed my Apple and does anyone know of a service that I could use as appose to reinventing the wheel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is allowed by Apple.

There are apps on App Store that do not implement their own register/login mechanism. Those apps ask their users to login via Facebook. So any user who has a Facebook account, can login to your app using their FB credentials. You would have to use the iOS SDK provided by Facebook.

It is always better to provide multiple login options to your app user, instead of just relying on Facebook or any other provider. Allow users to login via GMail, for example.

Adding support for [OpenID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID) is another good option. OpenID is an open standard that describes how users can be authenticated in a decentralized manner, eliminating the need for services to provide their own ad hoc systems and allowing users to consolidate their digital identities. Users may create accounts with their preferred OpenID identity providers, and then use those accounts as the basis for signing on to any website which accepts OpenID authentication.